# What is this rotation effect/processor called? (Stereo rotation)

Tags: stereo, effects, rotate

I haven't been able to find this a plugin effect (or hardware processor for that matter), partly because I don't know what generic name it's known by so I could search.  Its purpose is to "rotate" the stereo field by an adjustable angle.

There is only one control, the angle (or **α**).

The outputs **L<sub>OUT</sub>**  and **R<sub>OUT</sub>** are defined in terms of inputs **L<sub>IN</sub>** and **R<sub>IN</sub>** by the rotation formula:

**L<sub>OUT</sub> = L<sub>IN</sub> × cos α - R<sub>IN</sub> × sin α**

and

**R<sub>OUT</sub> = L<sub>IN</sub> × sin α + R<sub>IN</sub> × cos α**

When used with an angle of 45° it's essentially equivalent to a mid-side encoder.

When used on a true stereo source (e.g. from a Blumlein pair) with a varying angle it would theoretically give the impression that the sound source is rotating around the listener.

Web searching so far has turned up the names of some plugins that *may* have done it, but the websites/product pages are defunct or no longer maintained (e.g. roundpan).

Answer (score 1):

Something like the Waves S1 and Brauer Motion might be the type of effect you are looking for. If not then I don’t think the product exists.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the plugins of Dear Reality. They have "dearVR MUSIC" and "dearVR PRO". I have used MUSIC to let an instrument circle around the listener's head with acceptable results. You can automate a rotation in your DAW.

(Note: Plugin Alliance has several sales over the course of a year.)